# Relationship between tightness and weak convergence.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

I am getting confused with the following set of notes http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/8112/notes/metric.pdf.

On page 10, the author states Prokhorovs theorem as follows: Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be a sequence of random elements of a Polish space. If the sequence is tight, then every subsequence contains a weakly convergent subsubsequence. Conversely, if the sequence weakly converges, then it is tight.

In the next section, he mentions the subsequence principle which says that $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$ if and only if for every subsequence of $X_n$, we can extract a further subsequence which weakly converges to $X$.

However, does this then not mean that if $(X_n)$ are random elements in a Polish space, then tightness is equivalent to weak convergence?

This seems fishy to me. Could somebody please expand on this?

Comment: Take two sequences that converge to different things.  Interlace them to get one sequence.  Tight but not weakly convergent.

Comment: Notice that in Prokhorovs Theorem, the weak limit of the sub-subsequences need not be the same. In this sense tightness is more like boundedness in the Heine-Borel Theorem in $\mathbb{R} ^n$.

Comment: Thanks @Jose27, that makes things far more clear!

Comment: @Jose27 This seems like an answer rather than a comment. Why not post it as one?