# Is it true that any sequence of random variables that converge in distribution is tight?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let the sequence of real random variables $\{X_n\} \to X$ in **distribution** (but not necessarily in probability). Is it true that $\{X_n\}$ form a tight sequence, and if yes, how do we prove it?

So we need to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0,$ there is a positive number $K\equiv K_{\epsilon}>0$ so that $P[|X_n|>K]<\epsilon.$ My problem is connecting the distribution function of $X_n$ with $K.$ If $\{X_n\} \to X$ in probability, then the proof seems a bit more manageable, but not quite: in this case we can see that $P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]\to 0,$ so $K_{\epsilon}$ can be a random set $[X-\epsilon, X+\epsilon],$ but we want $K$ to be a deterministic set, not a random set. So I'm stuck even how to show that if  $\{X_n\} \to X$ in probability means $\{X_n\}$ is tight, but I've no idea in the case where  $\{X_n\} \to X$ in distribution only.

I've looked at this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3237475/relationship-between-tightness-and-weak-convergence), but it didn't quite answer my question.

**UPDATE:**

Following the suggestion provided by @kimchilover (first comment below), I tried the following, is this correct?

consider the sequence $X_n\to_{d}X, n\to \infty.$ By Portemeanteau theorem, $P [X_n \in K]\to P[X \in K]$ for any compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R},$ since **any** such $K$ has boundary of $m$-dimensional Lebesgue measure zero. Next use the fact that for every $\epsilon >0, \exists K \equiv K_{\epsilon}$ compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so that $P[X\in K] > 1-\epsilon \implies lim_{n\to \infty} P[X_n \in K] > 1-\epsilon \implies P[X_n \in K] > 1-\epsilon/2$ for large enough $n\in \mathbb{N},$ proving that $\{X_n\}$ is tight.

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: Do you know the Portmanteau theorem?  If so, find a continuity point of the distribution function of $X$ for which...

Comment: How did the related question not answer yours? They state [Prokhorov's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem) which is the relevant source here! An easy proof of this special property can also be done through [Skorokhod's Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem) that strengthens weak convergence to almost sure convergence! So that your proof actually does work!

Comment: @kimchilover  I'm sure that your comment is quite useful, but I'm having trouble connecting the statement of the Portemanteau theorem to my problem (there are several equivalent statements), but should I use the statement that says: $lim_{n\to \infty}P(X_n\in K)= P(X \in K)$ for any compact (that are closed in finite dimensions) set $K$ so that $\partial{K}$ has zero Lebesgue measure? Then use the fact that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists K$ compact so that $P(K)\ge 1-\epsilon,$ so from the Portemeanteau, $P(X_n \in K)\ge 1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for large enough $n,$ hence proving the statement?

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard question to answer because you have not given much indication of what you know and of what your precise definitions are.

Here is an argument.  Let $F_n$ and $F$ denote the distribution functions for $|X_n|$ and $|X|$.  Since $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution, we know (by the Portmanteau theorem) that $F_n(x)\to F(x)$ for all continuity points $x$ of $F$.  But $F$ has at most countably many discontinuities, so for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a continuity point $x_\epsilon$ for which
$F_n(x_\epsilon)\to F(x_\epsilon)>1-\epsilon$. So $P(|X_n|> x_\epsilon)<\epsilon$ for all but finitely many $n$.  So there exists a $k_\epsilon$ such that $P(|X_n|>k_\epsilon)<\epsilon$ for all $n$: just take $k_\epsilon>x_\epsilon$ large enough to take care of the finitely many exceptions; this does not harm the non-exceptional $n$.  Finally, use the compact set $K_\epsilon=\{x: |x|\le k_\epsilon\}$ to verify tightness of the $X_n$.